# Accessing Azure Service Bus Topic Url denied with a 401

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

When I click on the link to the topic (from the azure topic dashboard view) this error is displayed:

```
  <Error>
      <Code>401</Code>
      <Detail>Manage claim is required for this operation. TrackingId:###,TimeStamp:1/21/2015 4:24:20 AM</Detail>
  </Error>
```

Earlier I configured additional shared access policies because the only one defined had all permissions assigned to it and I wanted the service to use a listen/send only.

The messages are being sent successfully to the topic using the new policy. I can verify via the topic monitor view.

topic client:

```
  serviceBusClient = azure.createServiceBusService(config.btsServiceBus.TOPIC_CONN);

  serviceBusClient.sendTopicMessage(topic, this.message, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log('btsServiceBusAzure sending error' + error);
        }
        else{
            console.log('btsServiceBusAzure: message sent');
        }
    });
```

I'm stumped on what to do get the link in azure to display again. I can't see anything "off" in the topic configure screen.

Thanks!

Comment: Nah, never did. I went another route :-/ @Carl

Comment: Not sure if it was the same issues, but I was using the wrong connection string. From the azure dashboard I wasn't choosing the namespace connection string

Comment: Hmmmm, thanks @Carl. I can't remember now lol but I thought I had the correct string frmo the dashboard. I'll certainly keep that in mind next time.